# How to alphabetize strings with diacritics?

Tags: sorting

**Q:** how do I alphabetize strings with diacritics?

#### Problem

I have a long list of author names, some of whom have letters with
diacritics in their names (e.g., "á" or "é").  I want to sort this
list alphabetically.

The problem: `sort`ing the list with `string-lessp` does *not* sort them alphabetically.

According to the accepted answer
in
[this post from a sister site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212614/where-does-%C3%B6-fall-in-alphabetical-ordering/212630),
English ignores the diacritics in sorting except to break ties.
(Other languages do it differently.)

#### Toy Example

Here's a toy example.  The list of letters that I start with is
already ordered alphabetically.  When I `sort` this list with
`string-lessp`, however, it sorts them in what I presume is
unicode point order rather than alphabetical order:

```el
(let ((letters '("a" "à" "á" "â" "b" "c" "e" "é" "ê")))
  (sort letters #'string-lessp))
;; => ("a" "b" "c" "e" "à" "á" "â" "é" "ê")
```

#### What Do I Do?

*How can I alphabetize strings with diacritics in them?*

At a minimum, I'd like to respect the "ignore diacritics except to
break ties" rule described above.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to
alphabetize according to an arbitrarily defined language, but I'll
happily settle for English.

Comment: Good question. I wonder whether it depends on - or should depend on - your OS language setting. Alphabetization is language-dependent, in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your system locale is set to something that will properly collate diacritics (*not* `POSIX`), this should work for you:

```el
(let ((letters '("é" "a" "à" "c" "â" "b" "á" "e" "ê")))
  (sort letters #'string-collate-lessp))
;; => ("a" "á" "à" "â" "b" "c" "e" "é" "ê")
```

If that doesn't work, you can supply a locale string as the third argument to `string-collate-lessp` to get what you want.  With American English on a POSIX system, for example:

```el
(let ((letters '("é" "a" "à" "c" "â" "b" "á" "e" "ê")))
  (sort letters (lambda (a b) (string-collate-lessp a b "en_US.UTF-8"))))
```

(For American English on MS-Windows, replace `"en_US.UTF-8"` with `"enu_USA.1252"`.)

If you want to dig into this a little more to see what happens under the hood, I recommend taking a look at the function definition of `str_collate` in `src/sysdep.c`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!  As an aside, could you mention where one can look up the locale strings for non-American English languages?

Comment: @Dan That is system-dependent information AFAIK. Although not a listing of locale identifiers, [this Q&A from unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149111/what-should-i-set-my-locale-to-and-what-are-the-implications-of-doing-so) should help you formulate good values on most unix-like systems.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up!